# Class & return Function treated differently

Tags: typescript

In the code below, class implement "Validator" produce error, while function that return "Validator" does not, i have tried many changes but class still produce error, am i missing something along the way?

```
interface Value<Value = unknown> {
    value: Value;
}

interface Validator<Base = unknown> {
    validate<Argument extends Base>(value: Argument): ReturnConstruct<Base, Argument>;
}

type ReturnConstruct<
    Base = unknown,
    Argument extends Base = Base,
    Extent extends Value<Base>  = Value<Base>
> = Extent;

type InstanceConstruct<Base> =  Value<Base> ;

type InferArgument<Type> = Type extends Validator<infer As> ? As : never;

type RecordBase<Schema extends globalThis.Record<PropertyKey, Validator>> = {
    [Key in keyof Schema] : InferArgument<Schema[Key]>
};

// function return the same type with Class
function Fn<
    Container extends Record<PropertyKey, Validator> = Record<PropertyKey, Validator>,
>(
    validators : Container
) : Validator<RecordBase<Container>> {

    return <Validator<RecordBase<Container>>> <any> null;
}

// Class implement same type with function
class Class<
    Container extends Record<PropertyKey, Validator> = Record<PropertyKey, Validator>,
> implements Validator<
    RecordBase<Container>
> {
    constructor(
        public validators : Container,
    ) {
    }

    validate<Argument extends RecordBase<Container>>(
        argument: Argument
    ) : ReturnConstruct<RecordBase<Container>, Argument, InstanceConstruct<RecordBase<Container>>> {

        return <ReturnConstruct<RecordBase<Container>, Argument, InstanceConstruct<RecordBase<Container>>>><any>null;
    }
}

class Type implements Validator<
    any
    > {
    validate<Argument extends any>(value: Argument): ReturnConstruct<any, Argument, InstanceConstruct<any>> {

        return <ReturnConstruct<any, Argument, InstanceConstruct<any>>><any>null;
    }
}

{
    let argument = {
        data1 : new Type(),
        data2 : new Type(),
    };

    new Class(argument)
}


{
    let argument = {
        data1 : new Type(),
        data2 : new Type(),
        // error when using class
        data3 : new Class({
            data1 : new Type(),
            data2 : new Type()
        })
    };

    // error when using class
    new Class(argument)
}

{
    let argument = {
        data1 : new Type(),
        data2 : new Type(),
        // fine when using function
        data3 : Fn({
            data1 : new Type(),
            data2 : new Type()
        })
    };
    // fine when using function
    new Class(argument)
}
```

strangely wrapping in function produce **no error**

```
function FnWrap<
    Container extends Record<PropertyKey, Validator> = Record<PropertyKey, Validator>,
    >(
    validators : Container
) : Validator<RecordBase<Container>> {

    return new Class(validators);
}
{
    let argument = {
        data1 : new Type(),
        data2 : new Type(),
        // fine when using function
        data3 : FnWrap({
            data1 : new Type(),
            data2 : new Type()
        })
    };
    // fine when using function
    new Class(argument)
}
```

i am using typescript 3.9.7, i also tried 4.0.0-beta

[typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIB53YoC8yWIA1iAPYDuIAfMgN4CwAUMp8gG6Y4BcaPhADc7AL7t2oSLEQoCwACZwwVKLgBCcAM7FSFanUasOXXhmWq8AQSgBzLAFsI4ZBAAekEEp3JtevQAFBYCyHaOLuAAlIIAShBgWFAgAMJUIDpgUFgIYFq6EAA04Q7OrmD0YmySbOxgAJ4ADigJSSnpmdm5+exc-oXIJGSUtCBFfVwR5W6e3r4DekOLxZOcAKJeFe5bPn4EOAWBnCQHeAEQ9OyMJJveYNX1zSgAkl1wIEidWTl5R5fLISEf6MR5sRotZBvGDQaZRfIAFWeN2QSMhc1cC0UKjUGlAMKg4R0jAA-ETkIIQBBuNAwRDWhAEOolBdcABlBAACwgTjgO3mfnsGCoACNMAjOcAdAA6BJMqBKXAABSgVBaUEaAGkIA0StjVOp6CjTP0ANrahrIUDIcg6qgwZAc7m8gC6FKhIAJcIq7K5PLg5p1LquNTBAHow8gYGQ8sAMsgoIlkiBkGBucgdHAXKnnsgaMA08hUhhdDp2NHPmA4ymAGIgXBrIsZMBwUDQfmYvxy5nK1XqrU6vWYKy4lHdhW9tXQAe6oEjw0TNjBRsWedQPyCTotttQdjRd363G4ccswq4LetqlQI3MKRmTiJ9op-DDnHqY+M5msi87o2MXAfA0jAgFgGAYNUtTsBGRYljofjAE4TQYDy2yZtm9J5gWnJRjGVYZOwCCwX4xalg295NuAl7thiezICek79g0FpDpYb7Xss9EqlOGpMYOc5sfQi6MAhSEoeA+yvgaGiNie37NlR17XLe5FMl0vy4kEjb9E0WAipYCA8JJuIbhR25Xou-T7iaXCQeRq44rYZTwh2tGyWeP5Xkamnkf0cBORUgjeuAjb7vESYdBkPw9B+8qnno57yb+JRBWAJRvFkHxfJF3R-G58UedAf7KVpXCPsmyAfk+3w5fkeV4AV17Jf54Bpe8nwQNV6kxV+7mJZ5f4ASAQEgWB1T9LUtmEaWqK5iJyHwhJrFSWRvlDY2JgrkZjmRNsNELIBwShBAgXNWAsR0eFaTZV1gFNTtLUehl7WddFB0bXUPmlZdFVtMmL1-LdpT3alj0ts912vUNA0HSN4GNhNd7WZwyFgMgfnA8sSP9MgOJwAAjO6VI0DNLRBNEFnY5wuMAEyExAxNohAZMU5w4hgv0RMwaWQTozMZ0SHe7BYyjaOnZjJVU6o+N0wzzzMxLONS7TlL0yTTPkwr0HQKqhI0NyKZYDooD2MgU1wQruMAMwy1zcFBFjlOSy2BMq7LpMa59lM0zbjNkwr4jRPD7NcFrUA63m+ukEbIAm2bZbkZzJF27z8KBzUiONiLKfbCQDtcLjLvIJzvse47istsrReqyXLPY9BMBthHrhR8bOGVtWFtS9bgh1vbCv9AXPty6XZf50rQ-u-7afjWNIeRg3VJNwb0cmxWsb4QnqtJzoPOnWntlr3htYgAA6lAcBNCtXANS5CycX2068bOh6Ghxn4TlxjHMfxUmCet3n9HslJEyDU9wHiMu+OqCVKK-neo2MqKQq7E23iECB65ogQSFpnRIosMa507s7Ce6ta4D3Hq7NW8tPbIHro3PWzdDat0Ph3KhVt3R1jPhfPuVDSGEPITXfuY8K5EL9lQgOQdGw0MXnQ5ejDcLMI5lvIiu9gb7yAA)

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I suppose the difference is that `new Class(argument)` does return a `Class<typeof argument>`, which might **implement** the `Validator<RecordBase<typeof argument>>` interface, but it does not directly return a value with exactly that interface, so type inference will work somehow differently.

Comment: I suspect it's because `Argument extends Base` in `Validator`. Just because your `Base` generic types are compatible does not mean the corresponding `Argument` generic types will be compatible.

Comment: @Bergi "inference will work somehow differently" i think you are right, Class somehow handled differently

Comment: @zerkms it make sense if function also give error, witch indicate incompatible type inserted along the way, casting   
data3 : <Validator<RecordBase<typeof sub>>>new Class(sub) fine though

Comment: @Andikac "casting data3 ... fine though" --- `as` operator does not guarantee type safety.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has got confused by the morass of types it's being asked to deal with.

I think all you need to do is give it some help.  Explicitly casting the Class you're adding as data3 to the correct type allows the top-level Class to be constructed without errors:

```
{
    let argument = {
        data1: new Type(),
        data2: new Type(),
        data3: (new Class({
            data1: new Type(),
            data2: new Type()
        })) as Validator<RecordBase<Record<PropertyKey, Validator>>>
    };

    // Instantiates without error now we have the cast above
    new Class(argument)
}
```

Comment: but but that what compiler should be good at :)

i guess ill implement and use factory function like in the code, i just feel pre-defined type and implementation less useful if you end up still need to type cast it